# How to remove the handles from this faucet

Tags: faucet, bathroom-fixtures

[image: My Faucet]

My bathroom faucet is leaking around the base of my right handle.  With previous faucets I've been able to use a set screw to loosen the handle and replace the washer.  With these, though, I can't seem to pop off the faucet handle.  Does anyone know how to remove this handle?  Does anyone know the brand of this faucet?

### Update -- Nov 29th

I've already tried to get those cap ends off.  I tried to use some pliers and unscrew them, but couldn't remove it.  I tried taking a small flat head and popping off the ends.  Still nothing.  It doesn't seem like the come off.

I also tried unscrewing the handles, but they just don't see to turn for me.

Also there is definitely no set screw on the handles.  I've searched all around the faucet and found nothing indicating a set screw.

Comment: Should be a set screw at or near the base of the lever....

Comment: Can't tell what brand it is (there are hundreds, both foreign and domestic) but in the absence of a set screw it will very likely screw apart, starting at the top. Shut off the water prior to trying.

Comment: Doesn't seem to screw apart and there is definitely no set screw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have THE EXACT faucet. There is NO screw. JUST PULL UP!  May have to do a slight pry on the base but that is what it is, no screws.

Comment: It's hard to argue with "exact!"

Comment: You simply pull it up by the handles?

Answer (score 1):

If the end caps don't come off, and there isn't a set screw, try simply pulling up (or taking a flat head screw driver with a towel so you don't scratch the faucet, and prying up). I'd recommend shutting off the water underneath the sink first (just in case).

If that doesn't work look underneath for some type of odd contraption to hold them on, but that would be a terrible design.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old but if anyone else needs this information, the handles do pry off. I have this exact same faucet and I could not figure it out. I tried to pry them off but I did not want to use too much force without being sure. I removed the entire faucet from the sink and brought it into Home Depot. An employee was able to pry it off with a screw driver. In the end he offered me a new faucet at a discount. Since I already had it off, I jumped at the chance and just got a new one instead of repairing the old one.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.  I used a 3 inch scraper blade and a hammer.  I very gently tapped that thin, tapered scraper blade between the bottom of the escutcheon (the bell-like part between the handle and the sink) just enough to loosen it a bit.  I then was able to unscrew (counter-clockwise) the escutcheon with the handle attached.

Note that the escutcheon is made of plastic, so be gentle.  Also, the handle is screwed to the escutcheon by a screw that is located at the inside top of the escutcheon.  So, pulling on the handle will not work.

Answer (score 1):

I have one similar however there are 2 little caps above the stem.  I removed them thinking I'd see an allen screw, but there was none so I forced it off with a nail puller and discovered there was a phillips screw that held it on (really hard to see down  that hole).  So if there are caps on top, try a small phillips head first!  Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I have THE EXACT faucet also. There is NO screw. JUST PULL UP! May have to do a slight pry on the base but that is what it is, no screws. Try pulling up and pry at last resort. If you do pry be sure and pad so you don't scratch or damage the surface of the faucet. (Turn off the inlet lines in case something goes terribly  wrong!)

Answer (score 0):

sometimes, you take the end cap off of the handle, remove the screw.  remove the handle (threaded or slide-on fit).  then there is a little port for a set screw or just a metal pin that secures it to the top of the valve core upper spline.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the end caps are removable, the buttons on the very end of each handle. They may either pry off or unscrew. Then the handles themselves appear to be screwed on. I'm not positive this will allow you access to the washers, but from the photo those parts can be removed.

Comment: The handle part of the handles are often removable, allowing you to swap out handles (between wood and chrome). However, this is usually simply to change the look of the handle, and has nothing to do with removing the handles.

Answer (score 0):

I had one fairly similar that came off by grabbing the widest part of the "bell" with padded channellock pliers, and turning counter clockwise. Unscrewing that part subtly lifts up on the upper part of the handle, and pops it off. Brute force did not actually work, so if you've tried brute force and are stymied, try unscrewing the wide part.