# Anyone recognize this faucet? How to remove these faucet handles?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet, bathroom-fixtures

I'm trying to remove these bathroom faucet handles. There are no screws anywhere on the outside surface.

Is it just a matter of prying them off, either using a screwdriver or just pulling up on the knobs really hard? Or should I try turning the knobs the wrong way?

I don't want to force it, so I figured I'd ask first.

Does anyone recognize the make / model? It would be good to know what replacement parts I'd need to buy before I disassemble it.

[image]

Comment: See also https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/78912/how-to-remove-the-handles-from-this-faucet ?

Answer (score 1):

If there are no obvious means of disconnecting, it ALMOST has to be a "pop off" design.   What other options are there???    I'd take a putty knife and gently pry on it from different sides and see if it "wants" to break free.

Comment: "If there are no obvious means of disconnecting, it has to be a "pop off" design." Does it actually? It could be that the means to detach them is on the bottom of the mounting.

Comment: Highly highly unlikely.   How would that work?   And it'd probably be the stupidest design ever, unless the engineer had never climbed under a sink....

Comment: "How would that work?" Screws that slide along a track when the handles are turned? Screws attached to an axle to prevent it from being pulled out? Or, if you meant "how would it be assembled", I imagine that you'd attach the handles to the mounting, then attach the mounting to the sink and before attaching the pipes and hoses.

Comment: LOL Ok I'll play along... Ever seen one that mounts the handles from underneath?? 
 The "axle" you speak of is where the valve stem would be.   To say such an arrangement would be "awkward" is an understatement.   Are you just trying to be difficult or are you actually posing a serious reply???   Because I'm not of the mind to tolerate silliness ATM.    Would it have been better to say "It "almost" has to be a pop off?"  Because, ya know, nothing in the world is absolute.  And there's always somebody who's happy to call out typos and grammar errors. "These handles pop off"  There, I said it.

Comment: I'm not a plumber, but I do have a bit of experience studying engineering. I think it might be physically possible, yes, but I don't know what the standards are regarding plumbing. If you think that having a bottom-mounted handle would violate standards, feel free to quote them.

Comment: Who said anything about standards???  I'm talking about practical implementation and, since you played the card I'll mention I don't just have  a bit of experience studying engineering, I'm a degreed engineer with 30 years product development.    Your two ideas of 'how this could be done' are impractical.   Screws in a slot would mean the handle is never 'tight' because the screws couldn't hold it down w/o a little wiggle (fail) and running a screw through the axis can't work because the valve stem is there (fail).    "Physically possible" doesn't mean it's practical.

Comment: Any engineer with half a brain would also realize that any sort of 'bottom mount' on the handle would attract goop and water, and the fasteners would get gummed up and corroded fast.  Have you ever taken a faucet off a sink?  They're disgusting.  And getting at the faucet from underneath usually means twisting your body in contortions, working in cramped spaces. It also would cost a whole lot more than injection molding a snapfit.  It's just a bad idea. Unless the engineers goal was to create a failed product. Find ANY EXAMPLE of what you describe, and I'll recant it all.  But you won't....

Comment: See Kris' link to the a previous Stack Ex question below.   What was the solution there???

Comment: "Your two ideas of 'how this could be done' are impractical." Design is an iterative process; I was just throwing a couple of ideas out there. You could also do something like having a fastener around the axle underneath mount that is screwed shut. As for a single example... how about this, maybe? https://www.camperid.com/valterra/single-piece-kitchen-faucet-mpn-pf211323.html?view=702056#features A single-piece faucet intended for use in the outdoors.

Comment: What makes you think those handles don't  pop off so the valve seat & washer can be serviced???       Also occurred to me ....  If a faucet worked as you suggest, to remove or install the handles would require a second person to hold the handle while person #1 was under the sink with tools.   "Impractical"    After 120 years of manufacturing faucets, what you describe probably HAS been implemented at some point.   And quickly discovered it was impractical.    I also edited my original answer so it doesn't offend your sensibilities....

Answer (score -1):

[image]
[image]
I think I see the set screw at the base if the handle.

Usually a small Allen wrench.

Comment: No, those are just reflections. There are no screws anywhere on the outside--I looked all over, felt everywhere for them, on the knobs, on the base.

Comment: Oh my bad.  Is this plastic or metal under the chrome?

Comment: All good. They sound metallic.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/78912/how-to-remove-the-handles-from-this-faucet.    Check this similar question out

Comment: In the early 1970s I encountered a kitchen faucet that did not have replaceable valve seats! Is it possible that these handles are pressed on and are not removable?